# Weird `require` behavior in jasmine-node

Tags: node.js, require, jasmine

I'm using `node` 0.8 with `jasmine-node`, `coffee-script` and `backbone` in a project with this folder structure:

```
<project root>
 ` fares/
 | ` base.coffee
 | ` import.coffee
 | ` import_list.coffee
 ` spec/
   ` fares/
     ` base.spec.coffee
     ` import_list.spec.coffee
```

And I have the weird situation of having green tests when calling from a specific folder and red tests from another.

If I run:

```
jasmine-node --coffee spec/fares/import_list.spec.coffee
```

The test **passes**. However, if I run the whole suite:

```
jasmine-node --coffee spec/
```

The test **fails**.

Check the failing logs where I `console.log`ed the result of `require "./import"` and found to be an empty object (`{}`) rather than the Import class.

I don't know why this is happening, do you have any clue on this weird behavior? I appreciate your help, thank you.

[The gist with all the code and logs is in here](https://gist.github.com/3144960).

Comment: Go through this answer, It may be help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471965/what-will-be-the-difference-in-requiremypackage-js-and-requiremypackage/15471995#15471995

Answer (score 1):

I think you just are running into the fact that require in node.js uses relative path names, so an import will succeed from one directory and fail in another. it's the simplest problem but it trips me up all the time.

*edit* I did a closer re-read and I think probably you'll find there's a relative require of some kind going on inside jasmine-node itself. if you can kill the bug pls submit a pull req!

Comment: Thanks Giles, I'll try and take a look. I apologize for the late bump.